# using subroutines in python instead of if statements

Tags: python, if-statement, subroutine

I was wondering if i could use a subroutine here instead if so how do i or is there a another way to shorten this piece of code.

```
    if currency1=='GBP':
        if currency2=='USD':
            number=float(1.64)
        elif currency2=='EUR':
            number=float(1.20552)
        elif currency2=='JPY':
            number=float(171.181)
```

Comment: You could also shorten your code by removing the unecessary calls to `float`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could certainly make a dictionary:

```
currencies = {}
currencies['USD'] = 1.64
currencies['EUR'] = 1.20552
currencies['JPY'] = 171.181
currencies['GBP'] = 1.

number = currencies[currency2]
```

what's great about this is you can also do:

```
other_number = currencies[currency1]
exchange_rate = number / other_number # exchange rate BETWEEN the two currencies
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
Brit_converter: {'USD':1.64, 'EUR':1.20552}

if currency1=='GBP':
  multiplier = converter[currency2]
```

or, assuming this does what I expect:

```
converted_currency = currency1 * converter[currency2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary like so*:

```
if currency1 == 'GBP':
    number = {'USD':1.64, 'EUR':1.20552, 'JPY':171.181}.get(currency2, 1)
```

Also, notice that I used [`dict.get`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) here.  If `currency2` is not found in the dictionary, `number` will be assigned to `1` and a `KeyError` will not be raised.  However, you can choose anything you want for the default value (or omit it entirely and have `None` be the default).

Finally, you should note that putting float literals inside the `float` built-in is unnecessary.

---

*Note: If you plan to use the dictionary in multiple places, don't keep recreating it.  Instead, save it in a variable like so:

```
my_dict = {'USD':1.64, 'EUR':1.20552, 'JPY':171.181}
if currency1 == 'GBP':
    number = my_dict.get(currency2, 1)
```

Comment: Probably want the default value to be `1` instead of `0` so when the conversion is multiplied, it just remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Subroutines - in Python the accepted term is **function** - cannot replace **if** operator for a very simple reason - they serve different purpose:

- Functions are used to break down code into small, manageable units and consolidate functionality required in more than one place
- **if** operator changes the control flow

As it was pointed out above, dictionary is one of excellent solutions to multiple fixed choices.

Comment: Subroutines are different than functions. Functions have their own scope and variables defined in a function will not be defined in the calling context.